# Ошибка _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "image.png": no such file or directory при запуске скомпилированного exe файла

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Я пытался загуглить, но попытки увенчались крахом, поэтому прошу помощи.
Я скомпелировал код на Python в exe. Но при попытке запуска приложения, вылезает ошибка `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Pgas_done75.png": no such file or directory`
А вот если закинуть изображение в директорию с приложением, тогда все запускается, но это не входит в мою концепцию одного файла. Пытался указывать в pyinstaller --add-data, не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать файлы из запакованных `.exe` ресурсов, то вам нужно получить правильный путь до них.

Дело в том, что при запуске `.exe` файла, он распаковывает свои ресурсы во временную папку. Вы же пытаетесь найти файл в директории самого `.exe`, а там пусто - вот вам и ошибка.

```py
path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.getcwd())
file_path = os.path.join(path, 'img.png')
```

Данный код вернёт путь до временной папки и сохранит его в - `path`