# Как в Tkinter Python сделать иконку для окна в exe

Tags: python

Когда делаешь `root.iconbitmap("124.ico")` , чтобы была иконка в Tkinter она работает только если есть этот файл на пк , а мне надо чтоб при ЕХЕ он работал везде на других компьютерах без наличия на пк людей. Как сделать так?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `PyInstaller\auto-py-to-exe`, запакуйте своё изображение в дополнительные файлы `exe` - [как получить путь к запакованным файлам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1563585/562052).

Comment: "auto-py-to-exe" не явл. внутренней или внешней ....

Comment: pip install auto-py-to-exe

Comment: я пробовал , не работает

Comment: есть какие то другие варианты?

Comment: Может кто-то другой вам подскажет иные варианты, я поделился с вами тем, что использую сам.

Comment: а что конкретно в команде не работает в команде `pip install auto-py-to-exe`? Не устанавливается пакет? Проверьте установленность через pip list. Вы работаете в виртуальном окружении или глобально?