Не работает exe файл
Создал exe с помощью auto-py-to-exe, использовал одну папку и один текстовый файл, после создания файла закинул текстовый файл и папку в фолдер exe файла, однако программа не читает данные из файлов папки и текстового файла, код ниже:
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk, simpledialog
#---------------------------------------Функции кнопок---------------------------------------------- 
def btn_click():
    global current_day, nums, entries, subjects, file, lessons, days
    number = int(nums.get())
    subject = subjects.get()
    output_empty = f'Под номером {number} предмет удален'
    if number == -1:
        messagebox.showerror(title='Ошибка', message='Вы не ввели номер предмета!')
    else:    
        if subject == '*удалить предмет*':
            with open(f'Schedule/{current_day}.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
                day = x.read().split('|')
                day[number - 1] = 'пусто'
                x.truncate(0)
                x.seek(0)
                x.write('|'.join(day))                                                
            messagebox.showinfo(title='Операция завершена', message=output_empty)
        elif subject == 'Добавить':
            prompt = simpledialog.askstring(title='Введите новый предмет', prompt='Введите новый предмет')
            messagebox.showinfo(title='Операция завершена', message=f'Под номером {number} записан предмет {prompt}')
            with open(f'Schedule/{current_day}.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
                day = x.read().split('|')
                day[number - 1] = prompt
                x.truncate(0)
                x.seek(0)
                x.write('|'.join(day))
            with open('lessons.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
                subjects['values'] = ['*удалить предмет*'] + x.read().split('|') + ['Добавить']
        else:
            with open(f'Schedule/{current_day}.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
                day = x.read().split('|')
                day[number - 1] = subject
                x.truncate(0)
                x.seek(0)
                x.write('|'.join(day))
            messagebox.showinfo(title='Операция завершена', message=f'Под номером {number} записан предмет {subject}')
            
def clear_lessons():
    with open(f'lessons.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
        x.truncate(0)
        x.seek(0)
    messagebox.showinfo(title='Операция завершена', message='Список предметов очищен')
    with open('lessons.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
        subjects['values'] = ['*удалить предмет*'] + ['Добавить']

def clear_schedule():
    for i in range(1, 6):
        with open(f'Schedule/{i}.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
            day = x.read().split('|')
            for j in range(8):
                day[j - 1] = 'пусто'
            x.truncate(0)
            x.seek(0)
            x.write('|'.join(day))
    messagebox.showinfo(title='Операция завершена', message='Список предметов очищен')
    
def left():
    global current_day, switch_label, week, left_b
    current_day -= 1
    switch_label.configure(text=week[current_day])
    if current_day == 1:
        left_b.configure(state='disable', relief=FLAT)
    else:
        right_b.configure(state='active', relief=GROOVE)
def right():
    global current_day, switch_label, week, right_b
    current_day += 1
    switch_label.configure(text=week[current_day])
    if current_day == 6:
        right_b.configure(state='disable', relief=FLAT)
    else:
        left_b.configure(state='active', relief=GROOVE)

#---------------------------------------Конфиг второго окна----------------------------------------------         
        
def show_schedule():
    Schedule = Toplevel(Main_window)
    Schedule.geometry('1800x700+80+80')
    Schedule.title('Расписание')
    Schedule.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    md = (d1 := open('Schedule/1.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")).readline().split('|')
    tue = (d2 := open('Schedule/2.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")).readline().split('|')
    wd = (d3 := open('Schedule/3.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")).readline().split('|')
    thu = (d4 := open('Schedule/4.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")).readline().split('|')
    fri = (d5 := open('Schedule/5.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")).readline().split('|')
    st = (d6 := open('Schedule/6.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")).readline().split('|')
    
    (MainFrame := LabelFrame(Schedule)).pack(side=TOP)
    
    (monday := LabelFrame(MainFrame, bg='gray', text='Понедельник')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    (tuesday := LabelFrame(MainFrame, bg='gray', text='Вторник')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    (wednesday := LabelFrame(MainFrame, bg='gray', text='Среда')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    (thursday := LabelFrame(MainFrame, bg='gray', text='Четверг')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    (friday := LabelFrame(MainFrame, bg='gray', text='Пятница')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    (saturday := LabelFrame(MainFrame, bg='gray', text='Суббота')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

    for i in range(8):
        (m := LabelFrame(monday)).pack(side=TOP)
        Label(m, width=2, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{i + 1}').pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(m, width=30, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{md[i]}').pack(side=LEFT)
    for i in range(8):
        (tu := LabelFrame(tuesday)).pack(side=TOP)
        Label(tu, width=2, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{i + 1}').pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(tu, width=30, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{tue[i]}').pack(side=LEFT)
    for i in range(8):
        (w := LabelFrame(wednesday)).pack(side=TOP)
        Label(w, width=2, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{i + 1}').pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(w, width=30, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{wd[i]}').pack(side=LEFT)
    for i in range(8):
        (th := LabelFrame(thursday)).pack(side=TOP)
        Label(th, width=2, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{i + 1}').pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(th, width=30, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{thu[i]}').pack(side=LEFT)
    for i in range(8):
        (f := LabelFrame(friday)).pack(side=TOP)
        Label(f, width=2, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{i + 1}').pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(f, width=30, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{fri[i]}').pack(side=LEFT)
    for i in range(8):
        (s := LabelFrame(saturday)).pack(side=TOP)
        Label(s, width=2, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{i + 1}').pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(s, width=30, height=2, bg='cornsilk2', text=f'{st[i]}').pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(Schedule, bg='darkgray', relief=GROOVE, bd=8, text='Закрыть', command=lambda: Schedule.destroy()).pack(side=TOP,anchor=SE)
    d1.close()
    d2.close()
    d3.close()
    d4.close()
    d5.close()
    d6.close()
    
#---------------------------------------Списки и переменные---------------------------------------------- 

current_day = 1
week = {1:'Понедельник', 
        2:'Вторник', 
        3:'Среда', 
        4:'Четверг', 
        5:'Пятница', 
        6:'Суббота'}


#---------------------------------------Конфиг главного окна----------------------------------------------  

Main_window = Tk()
Main_window.geometry('800x600+200+200')
Main_window.title('Составитель расписания')
Main_window.config(bg='azure3')
Main_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#Переключатель дня недели
(switcher := Frame(Main_window, bg='azure3')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, side=TOP)
(left_b := Button(switcher, text='◀', bg='darkgray', relief=FLAT, bd=8, command=left)).pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER)
(switch_label := Label(switcher, text=week[current_day], bg='darkgray', bd=2, width=10, relief=GROOVE)).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER)
(right_b := Button(switcher, text='▶', bg='darkgray', relief=GROOVE, bd=8, command=right)).pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER)
left_b.configure(state='disable')

#Поля ввода
(entries := Frame(Main_window, bg='azure3')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH ,side=TOP)
Label(entries, text='Выберите номер урока', bg='azure3').pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=TOP)
nums = ttk.Combobox(entries, textvariable=int)
nums['values'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
nums['state'] = 'readonly'
nums.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=TOP)
Label(entries, text='Введите предмет', bg='azure3').pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=TOP)
subjects = ttk.Combobox(entries, textvariable=int)
with open('lessons.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as x:
    subjects['values'] = ['*удалить предмет*'] + x.read().split('|') + ['Добавить']
subjects['state'] = 'readonly'
subjects.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=TOP)
Button(entries, text='Отправить', bg='darkgray', relief=GROOVE, bd=8, command=btn_click).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=TOP)

#Кнопки
(buttons := Frame(Main_window, bg='azure3')).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=TOP)
Button(buttons, text='Показать текущее расписание', bg='darkgray', relief=GROOVE, bd=8, width=28, command=show_schedule).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=RIGHT, anchor='w')
Button(buttons, text='Очистить список предметов', bg='darkgray', relief=GROOVE, bd=8, width=28, command=clear_lessons).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=RIGHT, anchor='c')
Button(buttons, text='Очистить текущее расписание', bg='darkgray', relief=GROOVE, bd=8, width=28, command=clear_schedule).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10, side=RIGHT, anchor='e')

Main_window.mainloop()```
Не знаю, надо ли прикреплять папку и текстовый файл, учитывая, что в питоне все работает.
Возможно, что-то напутал с путями при открытии файлов, т.к. в VSC эта система странно работает.
Помогите пожалуйста


Файлы внутри exe или рядом лежат?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1563585/562052
